# JSON Output Converting to String Without the Knowledge

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following AJAX function that use to generate a JSON out put. Because of an error in the JSON WebService it generates some unnecessary XML and to remove that I have used JavaScript Regular Expressions.

***AJAX Function***

```
    function setJsonSer() {
                                var strWsUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
ids=ga%3A76546294&dimensions='+ 'ga%3Asource&metrics=ga%3Ausers&sort=-ga%3Ausers&start-
date='+retStartDate()+'&end-date='+retEndDate()+'&max-results=10';

 formData = {
                    'Email': 'clientlink@client.com',
                    'Password': 'password',
                    'URL': strWsUrl

                };
                     $.ajax({
                    url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,

                    complete: function(data) {
                              var responseText = data.responseText;
                              var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText.match(/[{].*.[}]/));

                            /*01*/  console.log("'responseJson' is " + typeof responseJson );


            alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson)); //or just `responseJson` if you skip
    `JSON.parse`*/

               /*04*/ Load(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

                    }
                });
            }
```

After removing the unnecessary characters the variable parse as a "object". It should be "object" so I haven't any doubt about that. You can see that in the line /*01*/.

So after that responseJson has to parse to the follwoing JavaScript Function.

***Java Script Function***

```
function Load(responseJson){


setJsonSer();
//----------------------------------------------- Rohan
var labels = new Array();
        var values = new Array();
        var catogories = new Array();
        var arrayOfArray = new Array();
        var rowData = responseJson;  

    /*02*/console.log("'RowData' is " + typeof rowData );       

        var inData = responseJson;

        /*03*/console.log("'inData' is " + typeof rowData );

        var count = 0;

        var headers = new Array();

        /*for (var i = 0; i < inData.columnHeaders.length; i++) {
            headers[i] = inData.columnHeaders[i].name;
        }*/


        var dates = new Array();
        var pageViews = new Array();
        var uniqueViews = new Array();

       /* for (var key in inData.rows) {

            pageViews[key] = parseInt(inData.rows[key][1]);
            uniqueViews[key] = parseInt(inData.rows[key][2]);

        }*/

        $('#container_2').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'areaspline', zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Pageviews and Bounces'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: dates,
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    month: '%d %b',
                },
                tickInterval: 10,
                plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend

                    color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
                }]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Visits'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: ' '
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                areaspline: {
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Page Views',
                data: pageViews
            }, {
                name: 'Bounces',
                data: uniqueViews
            }]
        });

}
```

But when I check the datatypes of rowData and inData variables like in the line /*02*/ and /*03*/ they show me as string. But it should be "object". I cannot find what have I done wrong in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a json `string` instead of json `object`. so 
replace

```
Load(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
```

with

```
Load(responseJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call Load function without stringifying?
Or simply use JSON.parse on responseJson if you need to stringify and send it to Load?
Your need to use parse method if you use stringify first.

Comment: Hi,
   Thanks for quick reply. I have used the Load(). You can see that in /*04*/.

Comment: You didn't get my answer. The line "Have you tried to call Load function without stringifying?" does mean that pass argument as `Load(responseJson)` instead of `Load(JSON.stringify(responseJson))`.  Anyways you got the answer. I'm happy with that.  Next time I'll try to elaborate more clearly.